# How to deploy a React app with Strapi (from localhost to an external server e.g. AWS)?

Tags: strapi

I am developing a website, where posts are published through Strapi. My website is a React app. For Hosting, I use (Amazon's) AWS.

My question is simple. I want to deploy my localhost application, and make visible to the WWW. I was searching for tutorials but could not find any that helps me in this.

Thank you!

Comment: If you need no backend look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html but I would also consider: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a React + NodeJS Express application to AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250087/how-to-deploy-a-react-nodejs-express-application-to-aws)

Answer (score 0):

ok deploy process is simple:

You get a server like digital ocean.

you push your projecto into a github repo.

Configure mongo, node, ngnix and clone your project into www folder

enter in your folder app and make `npm install --production`

latter insall PM2 and make it run

this is a little explaination the real explanaition you can see here:

[how to deploy strapi app on ubuntu server](https://medium.com/strapi/how-to-deploy-a-strapi-api-on-ubuntu-16-04-17f8fbbf5c5b)

The www you can modified adding Cname at your server and vinculing your dns with you domain in you name domain proveedor