# How to deploy seperated Rails API backend and React frontend on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rest, deployment

I have built a web application with a Rails JSON API for the backend and a React single page application for the front end. I want to host them on the same server. In localhost they run in different ports. How do I deploy them in production?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250087/how-to-deploy-a-react-nodejs-express-application-to-aws/41250688#41250688