# How to structure my webapp if it need to talk to another server?

Tags: angular, rest, web, cors

I have an Angular webApp. It is served by server #1. And most of its data is pulled from a webservice hosting on the same server (#1).

Now I need to add a new feature which requires me to post to a rest-endpoint on a second server (#2). I have two options:

- let my front-end UI talk directly to server #2, which requires me to
  change cross-origin policy, OR
- add a proxy endpoint on server #1, and let my webapp talk to server #1's proxy endpoint, which in turn talk to server #2's endpoint.

Which way is a converntional way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should talk to an API gateway which handles all the backend-related aspects. IMO, CORS should be the last resort.

Comment: But why it is common practise to download from multiple cdn of js libraries? e.g. jqueries, bootstrap.js, etc

Comment: Here's a great CORS explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311247/2178042. And here's another for why using a CDN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330741/2178042